# '"How to change the song in one time?" Audio Spectrum Visualizer (After Effect)

Tags: after-effects, audio

I made an audio spectrum visualizer similar (After Effects) style like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzAbmW09Zv4) with multiple solid layers. But I have a problem: how to change the song in all layers at once? Every layer has different colours, glow and all other effects but the song is the same, so now if I want to change the song I have to go into every solid layer and change FX Audio Spectrum > Audio Layer > Song Name.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking!

Comment: I ask how to make preset for change song in multiple layers at the same time

Comment: What do you mean by "Change song" though?

Comment: I think OP wants to replace the audio source in all layers in one go

Comment: Exactly Luciano i want replace the audio source in all layers in one go

Answer (score 1):

Using the Audio Spectrum plugin in After Effects, you can reference a layer (using the "Audio Layer" parameter) on your timeline as an audio source. To update all referenced audio sources in your project at once, you can precomp the audio track and use the new nested precomp as your audio source instead.

> 1) On your timeline, highlight your audio track. Hit CTRL + Shift + C (CMD + Shift + C on OSX) to Pre-compose the audio.
>
> 2) In the Pre-compose menu, name it "Audio Reference" or something similar, then select "Move all attributes into the new composition" and hit "OK"
>
> 3) This new composition will be added in your Project panel. Use this composition instead of your audio file when working in After Effects.

To update the audio file project-wide with a couple of clicks, just open the reference composition you created and swap out the audio file inside. This will change every instance of that composition in your project.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. you move only audio file to another folder or disk (any audio, either music / recorded files.).
2. Re-open the project file, it will show you (after effects warning: 1 file is missing and blah blah blah.)
3. just click "OK"
4. double click on the specific audio which you moved/ needed replacement!.
   It will show up your PC folders, and all you gotta do is select 
   the audio you modified/ New audio and just add it.
5. it will automatically refresh and load the effects you put in to your project. [It will take time accordingly with the audio file size]

This is just for the Audio effects though!